# Android app - bluetooth mouse - without pc app

Tags: android, mouse, bluetooth

Is there any Android app enabling an Android phone to pose as a mouse or keyboard through bluetooth without requiring the user to install an app on the PC? I just want to "pair" the "mouse" and start using it.

Comment: No. You'd need a app running on the PC. But, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248578/how-to-control-pc-mouse-from-android-device-without-client-server) might help you.

Comment: too bad, that post states it is a no-go, I imagined there would be a "classic bt pairing" like pairing a bt mouse on mac for example, just make - maybe the right question is how to ask it - make a smartphone behave as a bluetooth hid? dont know whether such hid protocol is actually supported - most mouses have a "usb dongle" but some like apple mouse dont need it, u just search for them and pair them with your pc if you have bluetooth... missing something?